# nullpointerexception on mapping pojo to json

Tags: java, android, gson

```
{
   "App":[{
        "AppID": 0,
        "AppTime": "08:00 AM"
    }],
   "Rows": 0
}
```

Here is my JSON Response, but when i map to my POJO class and access i get a `NullPointerException`.

```
ListResponse value = new Gson().fromJson(result, ListResponse.class);

import java.util.List;
public class ListResponse{

    public List<AppList> appList;

    public List<AppList> getAppList() {
        return appList;
    }
}
```

When i try to access my result in my activity class, like this i get an error.

```
public void accessData(ListResponse result){
    System.out.println(result.getAppList()); // I am getting null here.
}
```

**Update:**

My AppList Class contains, **AppID, AppTime `and` Rows.**

Comment: Is that just me or are you trying to define a zero length array **WITH** values in your JSON?

Comment: Your JSON object doesn't have a `appList` property, but an `App` property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are storing your response in `value`

```
 ListResponse value = new Gson().fromJson(result, ListResponse.class);
```

Hence try calling `value.getAppList()`:

```
 public void accessData(ListResponse result){
    System.out.println(value.getAppList()); // shouldn't get NullPointer
 }
```

Also its good idea to put a null check, if the value could possibly be `null` as:

```
 public void accessData(ListResponse result){
    if(value != null){
        System.out.println(value.getAppList()); // shouldn't get NullPointer
     }else{
        System.out.println("value is null");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use GSon to translate a `String` to an Object (in your case the `ListResponse` object), the names of the attributes in this class need to be exactly the same value in the keys of the json string.

The problem in your case: The key in json is "App":

```
"App":[{
    "AppID": 0,
    "AppTime": "08:00 AM"
}],
```

And the attribute name is `appList`. Try put `appList` in the json, or change to `public List<AppList> App;` in the class.
This should solve the null.